# Inverse for strtolower

Tags: php

Script turns `Barak Obama president` to `barak obama president` through `strtolower()`.

**How to turn it back to `Barak Obama president`?**

Want to inverse `strtolower()` effect withour changing core script.

Comment: What would the rules be for which words get capitalized, and which ones don't? Would the function have to recognize names and whatever else gets capitalized in the english language?

Comment: Even *Jon Skeet* can't do that.

Comment: shamittomar:  Nonsense!  Strings capitalize themselves when they see Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that unless you teach PHP to speak the English language. [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) will capitalize every word, but it can't possibly know which words should be capitalized if the information from the original string has been lost.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  It's not reversible.  How would the function know that the first two words should be capitalized but not the third?

(Well, if you can figure that problem out, then sure you can, but it's not trivial.  Figuring out how to handle "LeBron James" is just the beginning of your headaches.)

Answer (score 3):

Store the lowercase string in a separate variable to retain the original string.

Comment: Hah ... I'll buy that one.  They could have access to the original string.  I assumed they didn't, but what do I know? :)

Comment: Or store the original string somewhere that the script doesn't change it. Either way, you win.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rephase your question to get a solution.

ToLower is just going to convert everything to lower case, and ToUpper just converts everything to upper case. It does not care for the input it just enures the output is all lower case. So logically its not possible.

If instead your method was written to make only the first letter of a word lower case, then the inverse is to make only the first letter of a word upper case.

So making everything lower case, the inverse is to make it upper case. Turning it back to the original string is not a reverse of the method. As such i would recommend you either just store the original string, or work out what is your suitable inverse I.e. ucfirst($string) against lcfirst($string).

Answer (score -1):

ucfirst($sting)

Comment: Nope - what the OP is asking for is in fact impossible.